# SOAP with two certificates file and "Could not connect to host"

Tags: php, ssl, soap, certificate, php-openssl

I have an issue connecting PHP with an API which requires using SSL certificates. The issue is when I run my PHP code I get "Could not connect to host".

I was able to connect to the service provider using CURL like this  :

```php
$wsdl       = 'https://example.com/Case.svc';
$certFile   = getcwd() . '/certificate.crt';
$keyFile    = getcwd() . '/key.pem';
$password   = 'password';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,           $wsdl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT,       $certFile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEYPASSWD,  $password);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEY,        $keyFile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
$output = curl_exec($ch);

var_dump(curl_errno($ch));
var_dump(curl_error($ch));
```

However, I was not able to do this using SOAP:

```php
$options=array(
            'soap_version'   => SOAP_1_2,
            'trace' => true,
            'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
            'exceptions' => 1,
            'encoding' => 'UTF-8',  
            'stream_context'=>stream_context_create(
                          array(
                            'ssl'=>array(
                                'verify_peer'=>true
                                ,'allow_self_signed'=>false
                                ,'cafile'=>'certificate.crt'
                                ,'verify_depth'=>5
                                )
                            )
                        ), 
                        'local_cert' => 'key.pem',
            'passphrase' => 'password',     
        );

    $client = new SoapClient("Case.wsdl", $options);
```

It results in "Could not connect to host".

The Issue might be in the certificate itself, maybe I need to merge two certificate in one file. I can see that many people having the same issue, most of them did not get an answer.

Why is the SOAP code returning "Could not connect to host", and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some places for you to start:

1) What exactly is certificate.crt? Is it a client certificate, or a CA certificate? You are using CURLOPT_SSLCERT (sets the client certificate), but are using the 'cafile' file directive in SoapClient (sets the CA cert file).

2) You are using CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER = false, but in the other snippet you use verify_peer.

So try debugging a bit more with these changes, having the same type of environment.

Comment: thanks for replay,

as for (1) I have one file.pfx with password , i run the following command to extract 2 file out of it 

openssl pkcs12 -in cert_name.pfx -nocerts -out cert_name.key and 
openssl pkcs12 -in cert_name.pfx -clcerts -nokeys -out certificate.crt

the I run the following commanf openssl rsa -in cert_name.pem -out newkey.pem 

so I am lost , i really dont know what i have now

Comment: as for (2) I tried to set   'verify_peer'=>false , I got the same error

Answer (score 0):

If your certificate is self signed you don't have to set cafile.
cafile is only for CA chain.
local_cert needs to have both: certificate (leaf) and private key concatenated e.g.:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----  
MIIDsDCCApgCAWUwDQ....  
-----END CERTIFICATE-----  
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----  
MIIEpAIBAAKCAQEAsMGypi...  
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

For some reason self signed certificate don't work for me on ubuntu but works fine on mac os.